# Problems with utf-8 on unix

Tags: java, csv, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a problem on my CSV export.

I create a header file like this:

```
/**
 * @param builder
 */
private void createEntete(StringBuilder builder) {
    List<String> entetes = new ArrayList<String>();
    entetes.add("Date Sélectionnée");
    entetes.add("Nom / Prénom des Agents");
    entetes.add("Entité des Agents");
    entetes.add("Créneaux Mains d'Oeuvre ou de la Tournée");
    entetes.add("N° BDT ou Tournée");
    entetes.add("Rubrique du BDT");
    entetes.add("Type du BDT");
    entetes.add("Objet du BDT ou Intitulé de la Disponibilité RH");
    entetes.add("Compte-rendu du BDT");
    entetes.add("Commune");
    entetes.add("Durée du BDT, Tournée ou de l'Activité");
    entetes.add("Durée du Dépassement");
    entetes.add("Motif du Dépassement");

    for (String valeur : entetes) {
        ajoutDonnee(valeur, builder);
    }

}
```

I am using UTF-8.

Special character are poorly encoded at my export. I have **Ã©** instead of **é**.

Comment: Can you post the code where you output to the csv file?

Comment: We need the code that actually write the file. There is no problem in the header, you are only dealing with Strings in a list.

Comment: Exactly what piece of software is displaying Ã© instead of é? That software may no be interpreting your file as UTF-8.

Answer (score 2):

You have not shown the code which exports / writes the data out.

In that code, you could set a suitable encoding, e.g. UTF-8 (although your sample text would work with CP1252).

Note that whatever you read the output data with must also be set to use the same encoding.

So your data may in fact be getting written just fine, but looks wrong when you read it.

For example, try executing this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("out_default.txt"));
    writer.write("N° BDT ou Tournée");
    writer.close();

    writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("out_utf8.txt"), "UTF-8");
    writer.write("N° BDT ou Tournée");
    writer.close();
}
```

Now try opening the output files with and without the matching encoding set when you open the file.

My Eclipse defaults to CP1252 encoding.

If I open the out_default.txt file, I see this:

```
N° BDT ou Tournée
```

If I open the out_utf8.txt file, I see this:

```
NÂ° BDT ou TournÃ©e
```

But if I set the encoding of the editor to UTF8, then in out_utf8.txt I see this:

```
N° BDT ou Tournée
```

Comment: when i try your code i have for the two file: N° BDT ou Tournée

Comment: in that case I guess your default encoding in that environment is UTF-8

Answer (score -1):

Note that in Unicode, an accented character like é has two possible representations:

```
U+00E9 lower case latin letter E with acute
U+0065 U+0301 lower case latin letter E, non spacing diacritical mark acute
```

Note that your IDE or whatever editor you use may choose the second representation, which would result in yet another UTF-8 representation. (Feedback by @tripleee suggests that this is not actually the case, though it may still happen.)

Comment: -1 No, that's not the problem. Ã© is the Latin-1 interpretation of the UTF-8 representation of U+00E9. In other words, the output is correct, but he is inspecting it with the wrong tool, or the wrong settings.

Comment: @tripleee I take the -1, though the problem I mentioned may still manifest itself (perhaps with different garbage characters). You simply do not have any guarantee that é will indeed be represented as U+00e9 in Unicode. I will update the post accordingly.